# Android emulator layout issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-emulator

i designed a layout using the eclipse xml editor and this is how my layout looks like on eclipse 3.7in WVGA(Nexus One) :

[image]

And heres how it looks like in the emulator:

[image]

And heres the xml file:

```
                <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/background"
                    android:columnCount="3" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
                        android:layout_row="1"
                        android:text="@string/main_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/Title_Color"
                        android:textSize="24.5sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:layout_row="3"
                        android:text="@string/user_name" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText2"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:layout_row="4"
                        android:text="@string/pass_word"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />

                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                        android:layout_row="5"
                        android:text="Login" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="53dp"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_row="0" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:layout_row="2" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="72dp"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:layout_row="4" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="52dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_row="0" />

                </GridLayout>
```

Comment: why of all parentViews ,did you use GridView?

Comment: @YashwanthKumar yes i did. Im new to android dev

Comment: well a linearLayout would be easier in your case.

Comment: @YashwanthKumar please post an answer if you know whats wrong. Thanks!

Comment: sry to bother, it's not that i found where the problem was, i was suggesting a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a textfield defined with EditText and it appears like your username/password text in the first screen with the orangish borders around without specifying the  tag in the manifest file.

[image: Text field rendered correctly]

Now when I specify the , the textfield looks like your password text field in the second screen.

[image: Text field not rendered correctly]

See if removing uses-sdk makes it look fine. In that case, I would say there's a bug in the emulator code. I don't know what else to think.
Basically, I'm just learning to code in Android and this was  test app that I created and so noticed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. It's related to the uses-sdk. If I removed this tag, the textbox looked fine, with the borders, etc. But when I included this tag, the issue would come up. So then I tried setting the minSDK to 14 and targetSDK to 11 and still the problem. Then I tried setting targetSDK to 7 and the problem vanished. Looks like this is a bug introduced and something to do with emulator!

Comment: Hi your answer is vary vague. can you please elaborate on what do you mean by "this tag" can you re-write you answer thanks!

Comment: Please see below the new post for details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LinearLayout rather than GridLayout, and deleting those Spaces.

```
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:columnCount="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:text="@string/main_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/Title_Color"
                    android:textSize="24.5sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:text="@string/user_name" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:layout_row="4"
                    android:text="@string/pass_word"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_row="5"
                    android:text="Login" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

If you need to space the objects out, use android:paddingTop="20dp", or any other value